# Logout route or function for accessibility in a SPA

Tags: html, accessibility, single-page-application, logout

Is there any difference if we use

- a link with a route: `<a href="/logout">Logout</a>` , or
- a button with a function: `<button onclick="logout()">Logout</button>`

in terms of accessibility?

The `/logout` route would basically just redirect to `/login`. The same would happen when using the `logout()` function.

Are there any pro / cons for one or the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a complete answer, just some things to add:

You already understand the general use case of when to use a link (navigation) vs a button(JS based actions).

This is how i usually think about that in SPA:

In case of Login/Logout or form submission, although the "action" can navigate to a new page but it is indirect, it first needs to be handled and processed by the SPA based on which the decision to route is taken. 
Also, it doesn't make sense to allow Login/Logout to be opened in a new tab which links provide by default or for it to be bookmarkable.

Also think about what you do with SignUp or Login, they are buttons.

So i would go with a Button in this case.

Comment: *"doesn't make sense to allow Login/Logout to be opened in a new tab"*. That makes sense. At the moment the SPA has a `/login` route which shows the login form. When applying the same "design" to logout, this would mean, that the `/logout` route should show the logout button. I can only imagine one scenario where this is useful: For showing a "do you want really to logout?" confirmation page, where you have to click "yes" to really logout. But the conclusion then is: The "real" logout action happens with a button and a function.

Comment: **EDIT:** I just checked youtube and gmail and old fashioned HTML gmail. For all 3 applications they use an `a href` link. youtube uses `href=/logout`, gmail uses `https://accounts.google.com/Logout` plus redirect link, timestamp and security token as query params, and HTML gmail uses `https://mail.google.com/mail/logout`. All websites then redirect you either to a "logout landing page" or to the "login page".

Comment: For the Login point i meant that the form submission button for login after you provide your credentials is not a link, sure a login button on the main screen to go to the login route can be a link in most cases. Similarly for logout, you could have a logout route if required as you suggested and then it might make sense to make the logout a link instead of a button.

Comment: Great point about gmail using a link for "Sign Out" , when opening the link in a new tab they sign you out and show some information, which seems alright as in this case it actually makes sense to have a link which can be opened in a new tab

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about single page apps href would reload the page which you would not want. What you want though is to rerender the page. If you are using frameworks they have "routers" that do that for you but if you are using plain DOM I would suggest having a "render" div and let logout() do the rerendering.

Comment: Yes it's an SPA, that's why I mentioned `SPA` in the question title `;-)`. Btw. `href` doesn't necessarily rerender the page. You can listen for its click event and call `event.preventDefault()` and use `window.history.pushState` to change the browser's address bar. Nevertheless your answer doesn't answer the question.